# Css Conflict when using npm run build in NextJs

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, webpack, next.js

I am trying to turn a html/css template to NExtJS App , the problem is that the app is multi-lang So i have two Css file one for Rtl and other for ltr So i do the folowing:

```
if(router.locale==='ar'){
  
    require('../styles/Style.rtl.css')
  }else{
    
    require('../styles/Style.css')
  }
```

the above Code work fine when I use `npm run dev` .... but When i use `npm run build` i got some Conflicts because the two Css file are using same classNames and Webpack combine the two file in one generated css file.
So is there any solution for this or other way to import Css file depending on the Current Lang

Comment: I am not clear on this "but When i use npm run build i got some Conflicts because the two Css file are using same classNames" - Are you getting the right CSS per locale ? Do you see an error or does the UI not print correctly?

Comment: yes, the two css file should be separate but npm run build  put the two css file in one generated css file,